# Python - Webscraping - get data from grid and flex field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, flexbox

I'm using selenium and i can't get data from a DIV marked as flex from https://www.jpg.store/collection/hungrycowsbymuesliswap?tab=items

I need the value from the **asset_id** attribute (marked in yellow)[page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxId6.jpg)

My code only gets to the div above the value I'm looking for

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")   headless
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.jpg.store/collection/hungrycowsbymuesliswap?tab=items'
driver.set_page_load_timeout(4) 
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]")

print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

if I add another div to xpath, the code will display an error :
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just to search for element array with locator `div[asset_id]`, wait for it's presence, using `WebDriverWait` and get attribute `asset_id` for each found element.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.jpg.store/collection/hungrycowsbymuesliswap?tab=items'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
asset_els = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[asset_id]")))

for element in asset_els:
    print(element.get_attribute('asset_id'))
```